# How to update local database table with remote database table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have mysql table created/modifying in localhost.And I need to update those in my remote database.

I have gone through lot of post regarding this scenario and I found out that I need to use `mysql replication` for overcome this situation.I went through some posts about mysql replication but I couldn't understand how would I do this.

Is this the method I need to use? If yes Please mention how to use this method? 
Thank alot

Comment: Assuming you want a live update: MySQL replication isn't a coding issue, it is a sys admin issue.  Look up MySQL cluster on Google, get some specific questions, and take it to serverfault or superuser.  If you don't need live updates, then dumping the mysql table and restoring it seems like the obvious solution.

Comment: @Devon Thanks for your comment.Yes I need live update feature.